# Is there a way to get a checkbox component out of a checkboxgroup component in Vaadin 23.3.0?

Tags: java, checkbox, vaadin

I need a single checkbox component to add a tool-tip on it. However, the component is of a CheckboxGroup type. Is there a way to get a Checkbox component out of a CheckboxGroup component?

I have tried to look up different type of methods on the CheckbocGroup class but I can get the Items back which are a Enum type. I need a class that is a child class of the Vaadin Component class.
I was expecting something like:

```
CheckboxGroup<Enum> checkboxGroup = new CheckboxGroup();
checkboxGroup.setItems(Enum.values())

Checkbox checkbox = checkboxGroup.getCheckboxOfType(Enum.Type);
checkbox.setTooltipText("TEST");
```

Comment: Just in case the title on the label (not thec checkbox) is good enough, you can go via `setRenderer` and create your own label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem.
It is not the neatest solution but it does what I want:

```java
checkboxGroup.getElement().getChildren().forEach(child -> {
    child.getComponent().ifPresent(component -> {
        if (component instanceof Checkbox) {
            final Checkbox checkbox = (Checkbox) component;
            if (Objects.equals(checkbox.getLabel(), Enum.TYPE.toString())) {
                checkbox.setTooltipText("TEST");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Via getElement, I manage to access the Children of the checkboxGroup. In a loop, I go through them all and check if it is an instance of a checkbox class. If so, I cast them to that class and can add the tooltip.

Should the internal structure of the checkboxGroup component change in later versions of Vaadin, this solution might no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the CheckBoxes inside CheckBoxGroup.

I would suggest instead of creating a CheckBoxGroup, create individual CheckBoxes.

If you prefer to use a CheckBoxGroup you can add a feature request: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues